# How to save non-serializable objects in Android

Tags: android, serialization, android-view

How can I save objects of the class which are not implementing serializable?

For eg: [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) Class objects

Comment: You can extend them and make serialization methods.

Comment: create Serialized Object, then put in it the needed parameters from your View!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your class and make yours to implement Serializable:

```
public class MyClassSerializable extends AClass implements Serializable
{
 //...
}
```

***Note**: thx @MoshErsan, this won't work for the `View` class, because `Drawable` is not `Serializable`. You will have to serialize your view parameters instead, and then recreate your view with these parameters.*

Comment: Note, in this case it will throw exception, because Drawable Object is not Serializable!!!

Comment: @MoshErsan Oops, I did not think about it :/ Will edit my post. Thx